# What to do when the page rotation is null in an existing PDF document?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Hello I need to rotate pdf from horizontal to vertical view. I used the iText template for rotating page 90 degrees. Here's the code fragment:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfContent);
        decryptReader(reader);
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
            PdfNumber pageRotation = pageDict.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE); //this part always gets me null so it doesn't pass the if requirement.
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
            if(pageRotation != null) {
```

The decryptReader function:

```
 private void decryptReader(PdfReader reader) {
    try{
       Field f = reader.getClass().getDeclaredField("encrypted");
       f.setAccessible(true);
       f.set(reader, false);
    }catch(Exception e){
       LOG.error("Error descrypting pdf document", e);
    }
}
```

How to fix the null in pageRotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [iText Example for rotating PDF:](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/scaling-and-rotating-pages#1048-rotate90degrees.java) (adapted to your variable names)

```
PdfNumber pageRotation = pageDict.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
if (pageRotation == null) {
    pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
}
else {
    pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber((pageRotation .intValue() + 90) % 360));
}
```

As you can see, it's **perfectly okay to get null** as a result of that call that's simply because there's no rotation in effect on that page (yet). If there *were* a rotation, you'd receive that rotation and would simply add 90° to that.

Comment: Yes - as explained it's legal and okay to do so

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jan, I had no idea that the question was so trivial. I was still trying to understand what was asked here ;-)

Comment: Wow. I'm honored. You did a terrific job building this library.